# draw Logic gates with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to draw the logic circuit but I have some problems.
This is my sample code.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm]
\draw

(0,2)   node (myand1) [and port]{}
(myand1.out)  node (Y1)[anchor=south west]  {$A \cdot B$}
(myand1.in 1) node (A1)     [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]{A}
(myand1.in 2) node (B1)     [anchor=east,xshift=-1cm]{B} 

(0,1)         node (mynot1) [not port] {} 
(mynot1.out)  node (Ybar)    [anchor=south west]   {}

(2,0)   node (myand2) [and port]{}
(myand2.out)  node (Y2)[anchor=south west,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]  {$\overline{B} \cdot A$}
(myand2.in 1) node (B2) [anchor=south east]   {$\overline{B}$}


(4,1)   node (myor3) [or port]{}
(myor3.out)  node (Y3)[anchor=south west]  {$A \cdot B + \overline{B} \cdot A$};

%draw line
\draw (myand1.in 1) -- (A1);
\draw (myand1.in 2) -- (B1);
\draw (myand1.in 2) |- (mynot1.in);
\draw (mynot1.out) |- (myand2.in 1) ;

\draw (myand2.out) -| (myor3.in 2);
\draw (myand1.out) -| (myor3.in 1);
\node (Ah1)[xshift=1cm] at (A1) {$\bullet$};
\node at (myand1.in 2) {$\bullet$};
\draw (Ah1) |- (myand2.in 2);

\foreach \Point in {(A1),(B1)}{
    \node [xshift=.2cm] at \Point {$\bullet$};
}


    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{วงจรลองจิกตามสมการ $X = A \cdot B + B \cdot A$}
    \label{fig:exampleLogic}
\end{figure}
```

This is my result.

[image]

The input line of the second AND gate does not connect to input A.
I tried to create node name Ah1 with code `\node (Ah1)[xshift=1cm] at (A1) {$\bullet$};` to make a node point.
I draw a line with `\draw (Ah1) |- (myand2.in 2);`. However, a line does not connect to the `Ah1` node.

Thank you for your suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing can be reduced further, but the main problem you have here is to try to use nodes with a `$\bullet$` in it as a connection dot (called "poles" in `circuitikz` jargon). When you build a node, there is a separation (`inner sep`) between the content and the rest of the drawing, and [this is the gap you see](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#e5). So the best bet is to use the provided `node[circ](name){}` for adding the dots...

The minimal changes are these:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm, circuitikz/logic ports=ieee]
    \draw

    (0,2)   node (myand1) [and port]{}
    (myand1.out)  node (Y1)[anchor=south west]  {$A \cdot B$}
    (myand1.in 1) -- ++(-1,0) node[circ](A1){} node[left]{$A$}
    (myand1.in 2) -- ++(-1,0) node[circ](B1){} node[left]{$B$}

    (0,1)         node (mynot1) [not port]{}
    (mynot1.out)  node (Ybar)   [anchor=south west]{}

    (2,0)   node (myand2) [and port]{}
    (myand2.out)  node (Y2)[anchor=south west,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]  {$\overline{B} \cdot A$}
    (myand2.in 1) node (B2) [anchor=south east]   {$\overline{B}$}

    (4,1)   node (myor3) [or port]{}
    (myor3.out)  node (Y3)[anchor=south west]  {$A \cdot B + \overline{B} \cdot A$};

    %draw line
    \draw (myand1.in 2) node[circ]{} |- (mynot1.in);
    \draw ([xshift=-0.5cm]myand1.in 1) node[circ]{} |- (myand2.in 2);
    \draw (mynot1.out) |- (myand2.in 1) ;

    \draw (myand2.out) -| (myor3.in 2);
    \draw (myand1.out) -| (myor3.in 1);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]